# How do I format {{$timestamp}} as MM/DD/YYYY in Postman?

Tags: date, timestamp, postman

In Postman, the [dynamic variable](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#dynamic-variables) `{{$timestamp}}` inserts the current [Unix Time Stamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) into a request. (Represented as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970)

```
"currentTime": "1510934784"
```

However, the API I am working with expects timestamps formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

```
"currentDate": "11/17/2017"
```

How do I insert the current date (formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY`) into my request with Postman?

Comment: you can write JS code in pre-request script tab to do so

Comment: @chakri Can you explain in more detail with an answer?

Comment: Add below code in pre-request script tab
`postman.setEnvironmentVariable("$$timestamp",new Date());`

and in your request just use `{{$$timestamp}}`

Comment: ----------
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64893960/how-to-put-datetime-in-body-postman/64901448?noredirect=1#comment114769292_64901448

Comment: Fix your API... that is the worst possible choice for timestamps, since many parts of the world use DD/MM/YYYY and for days from 1-12 there is no way to distinguish between that poor choice and yours.  Use YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @JoelFan It was a third party API (Kronos Workforce Central) that I had no control over.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) with Postman to give you that timestamp format.

You can add this to the pre-request script:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("today", moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

Then reference `{{today}}` where ever you need it.

If you add this to the `Collection Level Pre-request Script`, it will be run for each request in the `Collection`. Rather than needing to add it to *all* the requests individually.

For more information about using `moment` in Postman, I wrote a short blog post: https://dannydainton.com/2018/05/21/hold-on-wait-a-moment/

Comment: this can't be true.. postman doesn't have support for loading external libraries right now: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1180

Comment: Hooo very nice. This will be helping a los with pre and post scripts. Thanks

Comment: To prevent name-conflicts, you might want to use a different name like `{{today}}` or `{{datestamp}}`.

Comment: Sure, it was purely an example of how you could use it. The variable name obviously needs to suit your own needs / context or what you're doing, is just copy and pasting my example into your solution...which is never a good thing. :)

Comment: Pretty useful referenced blog post

Comment: @abbood It's somewhat true: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries

Answer (score 77):

Use Pre-request script tab to write javascript to get and save the date into a variable:

```js
const dateNow = new Date();
pm.environment.set('currentDate', dateNow.toISOString());
```

and then use it in the request body as follows:

```js
"currentDate": "{{currentDate}}"
```

Comment: There's gotta be a way to get a date, without modifying a pre-request script for every request.  This is nuts.

Comment: There are global variables that you can set once and read other places.

Comment: Put the requests in a folder or collection, then you can set these kind of variables once in the pre-script of the folder or the collection

Comment: See my answer above this one. It shows you how to set pre-scripts on a collection, so you don't have to put it in each individual request.

Comment: Postman now supports {{$isoTimestamp}}, output: "2020-09-16T18:11:41.397Z"

Answer (score 23):

My solution is similar to Payam's, except I am using

```
//older code
//postman.setGlobalVariable("currentDate", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
pm.globals.set("currentDate", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

If you hit the "3 dots" on the folder and click "Edit"

[image]

Then set Pre-Request Scripts for the all calls, so the global variable is always available.

[image]

Comment: You could also use - `pm.globals.set("currentDate", new Date().toLocaleDateString());` Wouldn't this give you a timestamp in the format "DD/MM/YYY" rather than "MM/DD/YYYY" though?

Comment: Useful to note the last picture [currently] includes, "_This script will execute before **every request in this collection**._" That is, this answer is an excellent description of [Diceyus' improvement to Payam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355150/#comment102391582_54436721) that suggests setting a var with code for many tests at once.

Answer (score 6):

Any future date in JavaScript  (postman test uses JavaScript) can be retrieved as:

```js
var dateNow = new Date();  
var twoWeeksFutureDate = new Date(dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate() + 14)).toISOString();

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("future-date", twoWeeksFutureDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

In PostMan we have ->Pre-request Script. Paste the Below snippet.

```js
const dateNow = new Date();
postman.setGlobalVariable("todayDate", dateNow.toLocaleDateString());
```

And now we are ready to use.

```js
{
    "firstName": "SANKAR",
    "lastName": "B",
    "email": "SANKARB@GMAIL.COM",
    "creationDate": "{{todayDate}}"
}
```

If you are using JPA Entity classes then use the below snippet

```js
@JsonFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
@Column(name = "creation_date")
private Date creationDate;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDy0X.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BixUo.jpg)