# how to give current time in POST request body

Tags: rest, post, postman

I am trying to make a POST request to create a new resource. In the request body it needs time stamp that is current timestamp, how to add the timestamp , how to parameterize it to current timestamp?

Answer (score 7):

If it's a just timestamp you need, just add `{{$timestamp}}` to the request body as the value.

This would give you a Unix timestamp but if you want to use a specific format - you can use `moment` to do this.

[How do I format {{$timestamp}} as MM/DD/YYYY in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355150/how-do-i-format-timestamp-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-postman/47823708#47823708)

Answer (score 0):

In jquery do this:

```
$.post(URL,data,function(result,err){
     //do whatever with data
}
```

In the data variable have data equal to what you need to send. To add the time stamp use

```
Let ts = new Date(Date.now())
```

And set data as ts.

Answer (score 0):

`{{$timestamp}}` works only for Postman.

What should be the format to pass the timestamp directly to a variable of the JSON payload? I have been using Rest assured for api automation. Below is the JSON payload  and i need to pass the Current time stamp to the clientTime field

```
{ "appVersions": { "APK": { "versionCode":4150, "versionName":"2.0.3" } }, "bEnableGlobalPayment":true, "clientTime":1551829145, }
```