# How to Set to header part Date on Postman api testing tools

Tags: json, postman, date-format

I have been facing the problem. Postman Date format part.

I want to set to header area Date and time. like (Monday, 03-December-18 07:41:29)
and I tried moment.js import package. I could have not to succeed. How to add moment js on pre-request area

I read Postman documentation but  could not understand  properly

anyone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format {{$timestamp}} as MM/DD/YYYY in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355150/how-do-i-format-timestamp-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-postman)

Answer (score 2):

make use of the environment variable add variable `{{$timestamp}}` in the request.

on pre request add:

```
var moment = require('moment')
pm.globals.set("timestamp", moment().format("LLLL"))
```

Now, in your request that you using `{{$timestamp}}` replace it with `{{timestamp}}`.

Output should look like this `Thursday, September 4, 1986 8:30 PM`

[MomentJs format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats)

Comment: you dont need to import moment it is already an internal module in postman https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/. All you need is to add this into the pre request . var moment = require('moment')