# Postman: way to format a variable that has already been set in a previous test

Tags: variables, postman

I use `moment.js` to get UTC time in Postman.

The initial test will validate the format.

But as I go through the user journey and run more tests I need to get the same time but edit the format in order to validate it in later test cases.

Here is the prerequisite script I use for the initial test:

```
var moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("PnDStartTime", moment.utc());

var moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("PnDendTime+6", moment.utc().add(6, 'hours'));
```

So I was looking to format after the fact.

I know how to format the value, but not after it was set and moved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format {{$timestamp}} as MM/DD/YYYY in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355150/how-do-i-format-timestamp-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-postman)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using `.format("string")` in that chain?

You can change the `string` value to the format you want.

All the information about moment can be found in thier docs:

https://momentjs.com/docs/