# How do I insert an ISODate into mongoDB via Postman?

Tags: mongodb, rest, postman, isodate

How do I insert an ISODate into MongoDB via Postman? I have looked around but examples/queries on this subject tend to be just for ways of [getting various string formats](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/553).

I have an in-house API set up on my localhost so I am querying the database (MongoDB) with Postman. Queries & entries are written in JSON so I would do this like so usually:

```
   { "adminModifiedId": 1, "dateCreated" : { "$date": "1557510188"}, .., .. }
```

or

```
   { "adminModifiedId": 1, "dateCreated" : new Date(), .., .. }
```

Of course dates within MongoDB are in this format: `ISODate("2019-01-21T17:41:27.107Z")` but I just can't find the right solution here. I know that Postman does allow to set global & environmental variables within the `Pre-request Script` section but it does seem strange that a platform so established would not have a way to format or convert into an `ISODate` type.

---

Edited in response to @Danny_Dainton

**Postman body as JSON request**
[image: Postman body as JSON]

**Pre-request Script**
[image]

**Erorr response**
[image]

---

I'll leave this for a few days to see if anyone can suggest a pre-established answer (that doesn't require a `pre-request script`). Otherwise I will mark mine correct as the only answer that has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason other solutions didn't work for me but may for others. This one resolved my issue though so may be of use.

**Pre-request Script**

```
    let t = Date.now()
    pm.environment.set('t', t);
```

**Body (sample)**

```
    { "adminModifiedId": 1, "dateCreated" : { "$date": {{t}}}, .., .. }
```

Comment: You should add double quotes in the body. Like this "{{t}}"

Answer (score 1):

You could use either of these methods in a `Pre-request Script`.

Using the `moment` lib, like this:

```
var moment = require('moment')
pm.globals.set("ISO_Date", moment())
```

More info about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47823708/6028443

Or

Just use basic JS code like this to create the same timestamp:

`pm.globals.set("ISO_Date", (new Date()).toISOString())`

Once the variable is created, add `{{ISO_Date}}` reference to your `request` body.

Comment: @Danny_Dainton Thanks. Neither of these are working for me unfortunately. My `body request` is `JSON` attempting to insert into `MongoDB`. So after adding the `Pre-request Script` this is: `{ "adminModifiedId": 1, "dateCreated" : {{ISO_Date}}, .., .. }`. With the error `[Invalid Json: Unexpected character (&#x27;-&#x27; (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that in quotes `"{{ISO_Date}}"` - This is the syntax in Postman so there must be something else that you're doing. Can you update the question with an image of this in place and the error?

Comment: @Danny_Dainton I've just edited the original question with some screenshots to show what I've tried. `"{{ISO_Date}}"` did insert into the database but just as a string, i.e. `"dateCreated" : "2019-05-12T16:26:23.205Z"` rather than an `ISODate("2019-05-12T16:26:23.205Z")`