# How do I get current ISO8601 timestamp in Postman Pre-Query Script and Body?

Tags: postman, iso8601, postman-pre-request-script

Using Postman and the following code in pre-query script

```
   const moment = require('moment');
   pm.globals.set("timestamp", moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ"));
```

I get as a response

*Request signature is too far in the past and has expired. Timestamp date: 2019-11-30T10:11:10+00:00*

In body I am using {{timestamp}}.

I need timestamp in ISO8601 format.

If I use

```
    {{$timestamp}}
```

it returns a Linux date of 1575110444 which is correct today at 10:41

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this out [postman inbuilt variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments-and-globals/variables/#dynamic-variables)

`{{$timestamp}}` is postman's inbuilt dynamic variables which will return always unix timestamp.
what you can do is rename the variable you setting -

```
const moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("timestamp1", moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

and use it `{{timestamp1}}`

Notice the `$` sign in the inbuilt variable.

check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355150/how-do-i-format-timestamp-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-postman) for more info

**Update**

From June 2020 onwards there is inbuilt variable provided for this as `$isoTimestamp`- for more details refer the documentation - https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/#common

Comment: Thanks for your answer that resolved that issue.

I had supposed that the $ might mean it was Linux syntax but I'm no expert and I didn't want to assume.

Now onto a signature issue. I'm new to all this so am doing stacks of research to try and self-teach before bombarding others with my problems.

Comment: Also, I've now shortened it to        const moment = require('moment');
pm.globals.set("timestamp", moment().format());             and it still seems to work fine!

Comment: Shouldn't the format be "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ" instead?

Answer (score 30):

It seems there is now an `$isoTimestamp` variable available out of the box

Comment: This gives current GMT date time. What if I need current local datetime in ISO format?