# Setting dynamic global variables once for all tests

Tags: variables, postman, soapui, global

I'm in the process of porting over some SoapUI tests into Postman and I'm wondering how I can set dynamic global variables, such as today's date, within a variable so it can be referenced within the request body?

I can see this can be achieved within a collection using the pre-request script, but this would be an overhead where used across multiple collections, so can this be set at a global level once?

Comment: Check if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47823708/3190953) helps

Comment: Thanks Wilfred.
I think confirms my problem, in that the code would need to be written in a collection pre-script, which would need to be duplicated across all of my collections.

In SoapUi you have global variables that can be configured/scripted in one place and referenced across multiple collections.

Comment: If you set a global variable, it will be available in all collections. So you would just need to set it in the pre-request script of the very fist request or very first collection.