# How to Put DateTime in Body POSTMAN

Tags: spring, postman

I tried this one but didnt work for me.
I got NULL value of "date_creation" in DB (Mysql)

---

I used Pre-request script tab to save the date into a variable:

```
var current_timestamp = new Date();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("current_timestamp", current_timestamp.toISOString());
```

---

```json
{
    "rib": "123456789",
    "code_client": "3",
    "taux":"19",
    "decouvert" : "150",
    "solde" : "8500",
    "date_creation" : "{{current_timestamp}}"
    
}
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: i got no error but i got NULL value in database (Mysql)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to select Raw and type JSON for request body

You can check what was send to database by opening console view>show postman console

and then click the request>request body in the console

[image]

WHich shows what was actually send to server.

If its still failing then its not issue with postman but your application

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and i got the date in console but still NULL in DB 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Z8c.png

Comment: That's issue with your endpoint you should ask developer to fix it